# Updating multiple table fields following DLookup VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a very amateur access VB user.  I've been building a database to track recruitment processes at my work.  I've almost completed the "techie" stuff but I have been stumped by a problem for a good few days now.

I a table called "RecChecks" which can be fed by data entered in to a form named "RecruitmentChecks".  I have been using DLookups to pull though data from different tables when users are entering information on to forms (i.e. information about the vacancy from the vacancy form when entering interview details).  I have most of the lookups working, however I want to be able to look up the new hire's name from the RecruitmentChecks form (feeding the RecChecks Table).

This would enable me to enable DLookups to populate the recruited person's name when I enter a vacancy reference number into another form (tracking file movements), and would also be good for reporting purposes.

I would be most grateful for help to get this working.  Excuse the code if it is messy, I haven't had any formal training.  Here is the code I have been using thus far:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()


Dim Vacancies As Recordset
Dim RecChecks As Recordset2
Dim NumberOfTimes
    NumberOfTimes = 0
DoCmd.OpenForm ("RecruitmentChecks")

HireeFNameID = DLookup("HireeFName", "RecChecks", "VacancyRef= '" & Forms![RecruitmentChecks]!VacancyRef & "'")
HireeSNameID = DLookup("HireeSName", "RecChecks", "VacancyRef= '" & Forms![RecruitmentChecks]!VacancyRef & "'")

DoCmd.OpenTable ("Vacancies")
DoCmd.SelectObject (acTable), ("Vacancies")

    Do
    NumberOfTimes = NumberOfTimes + 1
    DoCmd.Requery
    Recordset.MoveNext
    Loop Until Recordset.EOF

    Do
    NumberOfTimes = NumberOfTimes + 1
    DoCmd.Requery
    Loop Until Recordset.EOF

DoCmd.Close (acTable), ("Vacancies")
DoCmd.Close (acForm), ("RecruitmentChecks"), (acSaveYes)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandlingCode

Exit Sub

ErrorHandlingCode:

MsgBox ("No Data to Update"), (vbOKOnly), ("Continue")
        DoCmd.Close (acForm), ("RecruitmentChecks")

End Sub
```

Comment: do you need to delcare `HireeFNameID` and `HireeSNameID` as variant?

Comment: I am also wondering what you are doing with `NumberOfTimes`? it appears to me that is just a record count of your table `vacancies`?

Comment: Hello - I am using NumberOfTimes to set up the loop.  So I thought having NumberOfTimes defined would allow my loop to update each record in turn.  Instead, it actually seems to update all records with the same value.

Comment: I'd like to help, but your code has confused me and im not sure what it is you are exactly trying to achieve unfortunately. Which form is this  `form_load ()` on?

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for your help.  I've changed the functionality and believe I have got it working.  I think my code was a little too confusing.

Thanks again,

Kind regards,

Pmc2014